# file_get_contents and jQuery pageless

Tags: php, jquery

I am using the php file_get_contents function to retrieve the HTML from pinterest's source tracking page, that shows all of the pins originating from a particular domain. Ex: http://pinterest.com/source/google.com/

However, pinterest appears to be using the jQuery pageless feature, which prevents all of the content from loading.

Is there a way to force the file_get_contents function to trigger the pageless function, so that the entire result set is returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried file_get_contents, but for some reason that did'nt give me much of anything, but cURL seems to work just fine for me.

You will need to have cURL installed on your server, and the libCURL extension for PHP, but you could try something like this and see what you get:

```
<?php
    $cl = curl_init();
    $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
    $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
    $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3";
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: nb-NO,nb;q=0.8,no;q=0.6,nn;q=0.4,en-US;q=0.2,en;q=0.2";
    $header[] = "Pragma: ";

    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.77 Safari/535.7');
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com');
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);

    $url = 'http://pinterest.com/source/google.com/';

    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $output = curl_exec($cl);
    curl_close($cl);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>get pinterest</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <xmp>
           <?php echo $output; ?>
        </xmp>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents(..)` simply gives you what you see as the Page source in your browser. It can't give stuffs that get loaded through javascript. The best way to do it in your case would be to look for AJAX calls (in the page source) that are being made. Or rather, you could just open up browser's utility to monitor page activity. (On chrome you will get it using ctrl+shift+J)

Once you get the URL to which the request is being made, you can directly use them in your `file_get_contents(..)` to fetch the relevant data.

Comment: in this case, it won't be enough, you need to simulate an entire session, keeping track of cookies and everything.

Comment: That shouldn't be difficult. Save the cookies you get on the first request and send them for further requests. May be if the server wants it so, headers can be added before the request to make it 'browser-like'